# Maven + Flexbuilder artifact source and javadoc attachment

Tags: java, maven, flexbuilder

I come to you today with an interesting challenge.

I have a **maven+flexbuilder** project that has a dependency on an external artifact.

This is specified with the following declaration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.abc.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-abc-client</artifactId>
    <version>${commons.abc.version}</version>
    <type>swc</type>
</dependency>
```

The commons-abc-client is deployed to an external releases repository, and is not available on the local environments for the AS developers.

The artifact is deployed to the remote repository using the followind command:

```
mvn clean source:jar javadoc:jar deploy
```

If I run

```
mvn eclipse:clean flexmojos:flexbuilder -DdownloadSources=true -DdownloadJavadocs=true
```

The dependency to commons-abc-client is properly generated (pointing to the downloaded-to-the-local-repo version) and it shows that the source is attached.

Trying to open any of the sources in the commons-abc-client throws an error. It seems as if it is looking the resources from inside the SWC and not in the attached jar.

Any ideas on work arounds?